# How to attach container app to action extension debug thread?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I added an Application Extension to my project (the container app ?) as an Action Extension in Xcode.

The action extension calls openUrl: in AppDelegate.swift of my container app with success :

```
    func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    // INITIALIZE THE APP WITH DATA FROM THE ACTION EXTENSION
    //...
    return true
   }
```

I'd like to debug the container app. But when I run the Action Extension in debug mode, the container app is not.

It it possible to run the container app in debug mode too ? How ?

Env : 
Xcode 7.2, Swift 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found it :

During the debug run of your app extension, and after your container app AppDelegate has been called, go the menu : Debug >> Attach to Process and select your container app. In my case, VSign (22220).

[image]

After selecting it, it appears in gray :

[image]